# Where does 'flash' belong to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The forth line below sets `flash`, which is a `FlashHash` instance.

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    session[:current_user_id] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully logged out."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Where does this `FlashHash` instance belong to? If it's a global variable, it should begin with `$`, and if it's a member variable of Application Controller or its superclasses, the name should begin with `@`, correct? Is it just a local variable that was created in "destroy" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the source code of Rails, you will find `flash` is a method of `ActionDispatch::Request`, and `ActionController::Base` has a `Flash` module that delegates the `flash` method from `Request`, so `flash` is a method and from session,  so it does not need a '$' or '@'.

in ActionDispatch::Request

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb, line 6
def flash
  @env[Flash::KEY] ||= Flash::FlashHash.from_session_value(session["flash"])
end
```

in ActionController::Flash

```
delegate :flash, to: :request
```